# Cause and remedy for gcc linker error on export of dll

Tags: c, gcc, export, symbols, dllexport

Windows C utility program (Pname.c) being compiled and linked as a dll. I am doing this on Windows 10 using CodeBlocks and Mingw/gcc. The link step produces 1 error as follows:

```
Cannot export NULL_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR: symbol not found
Cannot export SP2_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR: symbol not found
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

SP2 is a dll called to handle the Windows display of error messages.  These `IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR` parameters are in the "libPname.def" file, and my understanding is they are used in the "libPname.a" files.  Other than that, I have no idea what causes the error, why the symbols are not resolved since they are in "libPname.def" file, or where to start to fix the error.

The other kicker about this is, "Pname.c" is structured the same way many other programs are structured and the others link and run just fine.  I have never seen this error before.

Comment: Reduce your program to the minimum, and then provide a [example].

Comment: The error is caused by the inconsistency between the entry point name in the program, and the export name in the Pnamedll.h file. Once they agreed, error gone. Collect2.exe is one of the programs called by the linker, and if it can’t find a parameter passed to it from the linker, it will not run. IMPORT_DESCRIPTORs are variables assigned to the exported entry points. My understanding of the NULL_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR is that it is used to mark the end of a lib file when it is loaded into the program. The error msg doesn't really describe the problem.